# Help with finding an example of a reworded definition of the convergence of a sequence and its new meaning

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

**Question:** The meaning of the sentence $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = l$ begins with "For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that". Obtain a new sentence by changing the beginning to "There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon > 0$." Show that the new sentence has a different meaning by giving an example of a sequence that satisfies one of these sentences but not the other.

**Original definition of Convergence:** For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N > 0$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n > N$ then $|a_{n} - l| < \epsilon$.

**Altered statement:** There exists $N > 0$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n > N$ then $|a_{n} - l| < \epsilon$.

I think I get the idea of what the altered statement is getting across. It is saying that there is one value of $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that works for all values of $\epsilon$. In comparison to the original definition where $\epsilon$ is a function of $N$. So this idea is similar to uniform continuity, but not exactly the same. What I'm having trouble doing is actually coming up with an example. One way I tried to approach it was using the negation of the altered statement:

**Negation of altered statement:** For all $N > 0$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$, such that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where if $n > N$ then $|a_{n} - l| > \epsilon$.

But it seems my lack of sequence examples is hurting me. What is a sequence that would satisfy this ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  The only way we could have $|a_n-l|<\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$ is if $a_n=l$. So, the only examples of what you want are sequences which are (eventually) constant.

Comment: What I'm asking are for examples of the altered statement.

Comment: And what I replied was that the only examples are constant sequences.  Or, rather, sequences which become constant after a point.

Comment: But that satisfies both definitions.......oh....which would then mean almost any sequence I  choose would actually not satisfy the altered definition except for the constant sequence. That makes sense.....sometimes I try to look for something too exotic while the obvious is the answer. Thanks for you assistance.